# Java Swing Performance

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I have recently gotten into Java in a Computer Science class at my high school and I am trying to learn more than just the basics I have learned in school. Yesterday, I designed a very simple text editor I named Aqua that is written with Swing. For some reason, my computer drags a little bit when I run these methods. Is it because I have a crappy computer or did I write something wrong? Thanks!

```
private void save(String content, String name) throws IOException{
    System.out.println(dir.toString());
    if(i<1){
        dirCreation();
        i++;
    }
    try{
            String savedText;
            savedText = content;
    System.out.println(savedText);
            File newTextFile;
            newTextFile = new File(newDir.toString() + "\\" + name + ".aqua");
            System.out.println(newDir.toString() + "\\" + name + ".aqua");
            if (!newTextFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Created new File");
                newTextFile.createNewFile();
    }
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile)) {
            fw.write(savedText);
        }

    }
    catch(IOException x){
                System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
}
private void load(String name) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    if(i<1){
        dirCreation();
        i++;
    }

    File loadingFile;
    loadingFile = new File(newDir + "\\" + name + ".aqua");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(loadingFile);
    String out = "";
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            out+=line + "\n";
    }
    jTextArea1.setText(out);        
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a code review service. Please ask a more concrete question if you have one.

Comment: Post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @bigfoot675 go to `code review` now !

Comment: This belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Okay i will move it. Thank you,as you can probably tell I am new to this website lol.

Comment: *"Is it because I have a crappy computer or did I write something wrong?"* - Without even looking at your code, I predict ... the latter :-).  **CS 101 lesson #1** - don't blame the computer, the compiler, bugs in libraries etc.  The real problem is 99.9% likely to be in *your* code.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to be sure, but I suspect you're running your disk operations on the Swing GUI thread, which would give the impression of being slow. I recommend investigating the event dispatch thread rules: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Answer (score 2):

```
out+=line + "\n";
```

Generally not a good idea to use String concatenation to build a String. If you are going to concatenate more than a couple of Strings you should use a StringBuilder.

In this case there is no need to even do this. Instead of creating one big string and then using the setText() method you can just use:

```
jTextArea1.append(...)
```

for each String you want to display in the text area.

However, and even better approach is to use:

```
JTextArea.read(...)
```

The API does the I/O for you with one statement.

Same for saving text. The JTextArea API has a write(...) method.

Comment: Well, if it's out of a loop, that would not be a problem at all. By the way hotspot optimizer will use StringBuilders (or something like that) when it shall be optimized.